# Rails 3 - How do I get Rspec spec/ & autotest to work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, autotest

I was all setup with Rspec and Autotest before I updated to Rails 3.

When running rspec spec/ I'm getting:

```
* spec/spec.opts is deprecated.
* please use ./.rspec or ~/.rspec instead.
```

I tried changed spec.opts to spec.rspec and running rspec spec/ again. But now I get a whole mess of warnings:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: Use toplevel init.rb; rails/init.rb is deprecated:

DEPRECATION WARNING: reset_javascript_include_default is deprecated. Please manipulate config.action_view.javascript_expansions[:defaults] directly. 

DEPRECATION WARNING: RAILS_ENV is deprecated. Please use ::Rails.env.

DEPRECATION WARNING: Use toplevel init.rb; rails/init.rb is deprecated:

DEPRECATION WARNING: You are using the old router DSL which will be removed in Rails 3.1. Please check how to update your routes file at: http://www.engineyard.com/blog/2010/the-lowdown-on-routes-in-rails-3/.
```

Autotest isn't working either. I'm getting:

```
.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/bin/ruby -I.:lib:test -rubygems -e "['test/unit', 'spec/integration/layout_links_spec.rb', 'test/unit/color_test.rb', 'test/functional/products_controller_test.rb', 'spec/integration/users_spec.rb', 'test/functional/colors_controller_test.rb', 'test/unit/product_test.rb', 'test/unit/helpers/products_helper_test.rb', 'test/unit/helpers/colors_helper_test.rb'].each { |f| require f }" | .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/autotest-4.3.2/bin/unit_diff -u
```

:29:in `require': no such file to load -- spec_helper (LoadError)
    from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in`require'
    from spec/integration/layout_links_spec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in`require'
    from :29:in `require'
    from -e:1:in`block in '
    from -e:1:in `each'
    from -e:1:in`'

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

The deprecation warnings are because of your upgrade to Rails 3, not because of RSpec. Rails 3 has a very different architecture, and the API has also changed significantly. Have you run your project through the [rails_upgrade](http://omgbloglol.com/post/364624593/rails-upgrade-is-now-an-official-plugin) plugin? Also, check out the [Rails 3 Release Notes](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/3_0_release_notes.html) for help on fixing the parts of your application that rely on deprecated functionality.

The second issue is probably because [ruby 1.9.2 no longer puts the current directory on the load path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2900370/why-does-ruby-1-9-2-remove-from-load-path-and-whats-the-alternative). You'll need to manually include spec/ into the load path from your spec.opts.

Comment: Jacob, thanks for the response. I did run the rails_upgrade plugin. I will also check out the Release Notes.

Comment: adding spec dir to the load path fixed it for me