# Heroku app fails to start - `require': no such file to load -- sinatratestapp (LoadError)

Tags: ruby, heroku, sinatra

I'm trying to get my Heroku app to run using the `bamboo-mri-1.9.2` stack. Of course it's running fine locally on Ruby 1.9.2. But when on production it crashes during the startup on executing `config.ru` which looks like this:

```
require 'sinatratestapp'
run Sinatra::Application
```

My `.gems` file:

```
sinatra --version '>= 1.0'
```

And the application itself as `sinatratestapp.rb`:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'

get '/' do
  "Hello from Sinatra on Heroku!"
end
```

That's all I've got in the project and trying to run that on Heroku results:

```
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require': no such file to load -- sinatratestapp (LoadError)
        from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
        from config.ru:1:in `block (3 levels) in <main>'
        ...
-----> Your application is requiring a file that it can't find.

       Most often this is due to missing gems, or it could be that you failed
       to commit the file to your repo.  See http://docs.heroku.com/gems for
       more information on managing gems.

       Examine the backtrace above this message to debug.
```

I've tried to do as it guides but as a Ruby noob my examinations have resulted nothing.

Comment: I was able to repeat the problem. I recommend sending a support request to Heroku.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

By the help of Heroku support request and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2900370/why-does-ruby-1-9-2-remove-from-load-path-and-whats-the-alternative) I found out the solution.

Ruby 1.9.2 doesn't automatically include "." in the $LOAD_PATH. To workaround this, modify `config.ru` by stating `require './sinatratestapp'` instead of `require 'sinatratestapp'`.

Comment: The reason for it working locally was the obvious fact that I didn't use config.ru when running locally.

Comment: Thanks, had exactly the same issue. Wish foreman etc. wasn't allergic to Windows!

Comment: To test config.ru locally start app by using `rackup`.

Answer (score 3):

You can put the following line in your config.ru file and it will fix the issue as well. This is also going to carry application wide, so it will bring back the feeling of pre-1.9.2 behavior:

$LOAD_PATH.unshift(Dir.getwd)

NOTE: I was unable to test on Heroku

MY PROBLEM: Getting unicorn to behave properly with a (ruby < 1.9.2) sinatra application without a Gemfile, config.ru, or config/unicorn.rb.

Answer (score 1):

I believe I ran into this problem when experimenting with Sinatra. Ruby 1.9 doesn't include the current directory in the path by default, so you have to implicitly state `require 'sinatratestapp'` in our `config.ru` file.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the tip. There was no mention of the .gems file in the Heroku post http://blog.heroku.com/archives/2009/3/5/32_deploy_merb_sinatra_or_any_rack_app_to_heroku/

Answer (score -1):

My Sinatra projects have the same layout and look about the same, the only difference is that in my .gems file I do not specify a version.

my .gems looks like this:

```
sinatra
hpricot
```

Comment: Didn't help. Are you also on `bamboo-mri-1.9.2` stack?