# Rake tasks with Sinatra context on Heroku

Tags: ruby, scope, rake, sinatra

I have an app built on Sinatra. It's supported by several rake tasks that must be run to setup database, etc... The rakefile looks like this

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'rake'
require 'rake/clean'
require 'rake/gempackagetask'
require 'rake/rdoctask'
require 'rake/testtask'
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/lib/config.rb'
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/lib/autoloads.rb'

@db = Mongo::Connection.from_uri(settings.db_uri).db(settings.db_uri[Regexp.new('[^/]*$')])
@cache = MemCache.new(settings.cache_server)
```

Works well on my development machine. Now, the problem is that after deployment to Heroku, the `settings` object becomes undefined, so every task fails. Do you have any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the file where your settings are defined is not being loaded. In your `config.ru` change `require 'my_sinatra_app'` with `require './my_sinatra_app'` . Also [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3973806/heroku-app-fails-to-start-require-no-such-file-to-load-sinatratestapp-lo).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same problem when building a sinatra app - I wanted to run some rake tasks to perform db setup operations.

What I ended up doing is abstracting database connection settings, connecting, and schema operations into a separate class.  This class is then accessible by the sinatra app and the Rakefile.

My rakefile is here: https://github.com/brighterplanet/status/blob/master/Rakefile#L6
From there, check out lib/bp_status/db.rb