# Ruby - LoadError on require

Tags: ruby, require

I have the following two files: `main.rb` and `sort.rb` located in the same folder. In `main.rb` I have the following code:

```
require 'sort'

Sort.insertion_sort([1,2,3,4]).each {|x| print "#{x}, "}
```

When I try and run this via ruby `main.rb` I get the following error:

```
<internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require': no such file to load -- sort (LoadError)
    from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
    from main.rb:1:in `<main>'
```

Any ideas why?
Thanks

Comment: weird it works on mine. what does sort.rb contain?

Comment: i scrapped sort and tried to require rexml/syncenumerator and got the same error

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2900370/why-does-ruby-1-9-2-remove-from-load-path-and-whats-the-alternative/2902711#2902711

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The better way to use

```
require_relative "sort"
```

intead of

```
require "sort"
```

Thanks, @Jörg W Mittag.

Or you can add a path where ruby should search your files (can be a security risk):

```
$:.unshift File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), ".") # current directory
require 'sort'
```

Comment: If he's running using ruby main.rb, it should no be the problem here

Comment: if he's running from the directory with main.rb file, otherwise it will be the problem here

Comment: I am running from the directory with main.rb in it

Comment: Please do not ever do this. There is a *reason* why `.` was removed from the `$LOAD_PATH`. If you want to require a file relative to the location of the currently executing file, use `require_relative`, that's what it's there for.

Comment: @Joerg: Is something like `$:.unshift File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), "lib")` also a risk?

Comment: @Andrew Grimm: No. Any attacker who would be able to inject files into that directory would probably be able to just edit the script anyway. The problem with adding `.` to the `$LOAD_PATH` is when *I* can get *you* to run your script from inside a directory that I own, I can inject pretty much arbitrary code into your script by e.g. putting a file named `sort.rb` in my directory, which will be found before yours. Especially if you use `Array#unshift` to put `.` at the *beginning* of `$LOAD_PATH`.

Comment: @Andrew Grimm: Note, however, that this sort of relative `$LOAD_PATH` manipulation is still a smell, since your package manager should do that for you. E.g. RubyGems automatically adds your Gem's `lib` directory, or any other directory/ies you specify to the `$LOAD_PATH` anyway, as does Bundler, and if you use some other package management system, then it's the packager's and/or the system administrator's job to do that. You shouldn't need to do that yourself.

Answer (score 0):

try `require 'sort.rb'` and check permissions

Comment: yes it should work, specifying the extension just help sometimes getting a better error description. especially for permissions or file-system problems

Answer (score 0):

you would also:

`require directory/sort.rb`

Comment: main is in the same directory as sort.rb

Answer (score 0):

In Ruby 1.9.2, `$:` doesn't include the current directory (`'.'`). Either do `relative_require` instead, <s>or do `$: << '.'`</s>.

Joerg Mittag says that `$: << '.'` shouldn't be done because it's a security risk.