# Why do I have to interpolate Dir.pwd when using require or autoload in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, path, load, require

This seems to be a Ruby 1.9 problem for me, but anytime I try to require or autoload source with something like `require "lib/mylibrary"` Ruby fails with a "No such file to load" error.  I always have to interpolate Dir.pwd thusly:  `require "#{Dir.pwd}/lib/mylibrary"`

I see source everywhere that doesn't need to look up the present working directory to include source files.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `$LOAD_PATH` variable determines the places that Ruby will check for files to load. As of Ruby 1.9, the current directory is not in the load path by default, but you can use the `require_relative` method to require files relative to the current working directory.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2900370/why-does-ruby-1-9-2-remove-from-load-path-and-whats-the-alternative/) for more details.

Comment: You can see what the $LOAD_PATH is currently set to by doing a 'puts $:'