# ruby 1.9, rvm, sinatra and rackup

Tags: ruby, sinatra, rvm, rack

Gemfile

```
source :rubygems
gem 'sinatra'
```

config.ru

```
require 'app'
run App
```

app.rb

```
require 'bundler/setup'
require 'sinatra'

class App < Sinatra::Base
  get '/' do
   'hello world'
  end
end
```

rackup failes with

```
.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': no such file to load -- app (LoadError)
```

Works with ruby 1.8 . Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's because 1.9.2 no longer includes '.' in the load path by default.

See the this question for more: [Why does Ruby 1.9.2 remove "." from LOAD_PATH, and what's the alternative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2900370/why-does-ruby-1-9-2-remove-from-load-path-and-whats-the-alternative)

Answer (score 1):

Some notes:

Gemfile, I use gem 'sinatra', :require => 'sinatra/base' to load a Modular Sinatra App.

Config.ru, usually I set Bundler on it, not in app.rb, leaving app.rb clean to my app.

require 'bundler/setup'
Bundler.require(:default)

Comment: do you use rackup and ruby 1.9.2?