# Rake aborted! no such file to load --bundler/setup Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am very new in Rails.
after I created a new rails project.

```
rails new test project
```

I ran

```
rake db:create
```

In order to create a database. 
Found the following error message:

```
rake aborted!
no such file to load -- bundler/setup
```

I am running

Rails 3.1.0

Ruby 1.9.2p290

rvm 1.8.3

Thank you very much!

my $PATH
    /Users/Mac/.rvm/scripts/rvm:/Users/Mac/.rvm/bin:/Users/Mac/.local/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/X11/bin:{ANT_HOME}/bin

Comment: I think the best way to fix is to remove everything (Rails, rvm, gems...etc)... @_@

Comment: How did you install Ruby? Try `which ruby`, `which rake` and `gem list`.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Run:

```
gem install bundler
bundle install
bundle exec rake db:create
```

You might want to learn about [Bundler](http://gembundler.com/).

See the link on ["Creating new Rails Project"](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#creating-a-new-rails-project).

Comment: Hi. I have tried this but still not working. After it says 
   Could not find rake-0.9.2 in any source.
   run 'bundle install' to install missing gems.
I have checked that there do exist rake in my gem list and bundle list. Still don't get it. Thank you for fast reply. Appreciate it dude

Comment: I had the same problem with bundler 1.1.5.  Upgrading to 1.2.1 solved the problems.

Comment: I needed only: sudo apt-get install bundler.

Answer (score 12):

I had the same thing and here's what I found: You probably have more than one version of rake installed (type `gem list` to see), and your project is specifying you must use the older version of rake.

If you do, then the default rake is the newer one.

If you are in your project directory, and your project's Gemfile specifies the older version of rake, and your type rake db:migrate then the error message is telling you that the 'new' version of rake is not the one you specified in Gemfile, so run `bundle exec rake db:migrate` so bundler can pick the correct version of rake for you.

Answer (score 4):

try

> gem install bundler
>
> bundle install

to install the gems needed.

rake tasks will fail if you do not have the gems necessary for the rails app.

Answer (score 4):

I just had the same issue.
I didn't solve it fully but by running:

```
bundle exec rake <task>
```

I was able to finally run the task I wanted without the error you have.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to `gem install bundler`? I'd be surprised it doesn't install when you install the rails gem, but it seems that's your issue...

Comment: Hi. I have tried this but still not working. After it says Could not find rake-0.9.2 in any source. run 'bundle install' to install missing gems. I have checked that there do exist rake in my gem list and bundle list. Still don't get it. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: Have you run `bundle install` as it tells you? It's not finind the right version of some of your dependencies installed and `bundle install` should fix all this for you.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error as you while upgrading a non-rails project from Ruby 1.8.x to Ruby 1.9.x. The problem is that the current dir has been removed from LOAD_PATH.

[Why does Ruby 1.9.2 remove “.” from LOAD_PATH, and what's the alternative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2900370/why-does-ruby-1-9-2-remove-from-load-path-and-whats-the-alternative)

I had to change a few places from `require` to `require_relative` and then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Got the same missing bundler message running rake after upgrading to Ruby 1.9.2.

Rake needed updating and bundler needed to be reinstalled:

sudo gem update rake

sudo gem install bundler

Reinstalling bundler might have fixed the error, but you want to make sure rake is right too.

Comment: Yep. My problem is after upgrading to Ruby 1.9.2 too. 
After update rake and reinstall bundler still can't fix the problem... O.o

Comment: Does bundler run?  and did you update gem itself, with: sudo gem update --system

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Snow Leopard, had a similar problem recently. It happens that, for some reason, a system update created a hard link at /usr/bin/rake, pointing to OSX default 1.8 ruby environment rake executable. My 1.9 ruby installation is at /usr/local/bin, which comes later on my PATH setting, so when I ran "ruby -v" I got what I expect, same with "gem environment", but rake tasks were failing in the way you describe.

I just deleted the entry /usr/bin/rake. Moving /usr/local/bin up on PATH might've worked too. The result of running "which rake" must point to your 1.9 installation.

Hope it helps,

-- José

Comment: Hola Señor @José Fernandes. Gracias por tus commentario.
That's all I can talk in spanish :P
I am wondering do you mean that I've to move my rake to the PATH where ruby resides?
And by the way, I am using RVM. Do you use RVM? 
I've checked that my ruby and rake resides in the same directory. It should be working...Strange!
Path for...
`Ruby: /Users/Mac/.rvm/bin/ruby`
`Rake: /Users/Mac/.rvm/bin/rake`

Comment: Hi there. I'm not currently using rvm. If your situation is similar to mine, you should see some output entries pointing to "/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/" when running rake with "--trace" option, which is a check you should make in any case, if you haven't made it already. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

In your Gemfile, under group :test do add gem 'rack'.