# Ruby on Windows path for requires in dir not working

Tags: ruby, windows

I've a small ruby program that `require` files in the same directory. Program works perfect on my mac and when I run a test ruby script without any require it also works so. It seems the ruby program doesn't look in the current directory for the file by default. e.g. the `.` dir. In windows where do I need to update this so ruby does look in the current dir for requires?

Comment: The original [select isn't broken](http://pragprog.com/the-pragmatic-programmer/extracts/tips) anecdote was about someone assuming that something was wrong with Windows. (The link is only to an explanation of "select isn't broken" - the anecdote is in the book itself)

Comment: I own that book and have read it. Its really doesn't apply here. Ruby 'app' is surely portable between OS. I'd like to know is there a config setting somewhere for Ruby on windows that will automatically look in the local dir for required files.  I'm not claiming there is a fault with the OS just a question on how to config

Comment: @DerekOrgan: Just because there are runtimes for both platforms doesn't mean that the "app is surely portable between OS".  When you take advantage of system-specific behavior, such as the library search path, you lose portability.  And changing the ruby file to not rely on non-portable behavior is exactly the right solution.

Comment: Its a relative path specifically for the folder my ruby app is in not system specific. I accept that it was changed for a good reason but in general relative paths should be portable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I understand now since 1.9.2 for "Security" reasons they don't allow require to work like that anymore. The neatest way I found to solve it strangely was to put './' in front of every require.

e.g.

```
require "./myfile.rb"
```

Answer (score 7):

Chances are that your Mac is running Ruby 1.8 and Windows is running Ruby 1.9. As of 1.9, the default load path no longer includes the current directory. A common practice is to add this to the top of your ruby file before your require statements

```
$LOAD_PATH.unshift File.dirname(__FILE__)
require 'my_file.rb'
```

You can also use the shorthand `$:` instead of `$LOAD_PATH`:

```
$:.unshift File.dirname(__FILE__)
```

Another alternative is adding the load path on the command line instead:

```
ruby -I. my_ruby_file.rb
```

Comment: the idea of adding anything to the ruby file to make it work seems very flawed.

Comment: Another option is using `require_relative` instead. But they removed the current directory in Ruby 1.9 from the default load path for security reasons.

Comment: It happened in Ruby 1.9.2, to be precise.

Comment: @Derek Organ: Why flawed? You are using different Ruby versions, so you should expect having to adjust the code. Btw. the proposed change is compatible with 1.8.

Comment: I accept that now, at the time I ask the question didn't realize it was a different version on both machines.

Comment: @DylanMarkow `require_relative` is the best answer I've seen --- add it to your answer! :)

Answer (score 0):

`"."` was removed from `$:` was removed from Ruby 1.9.2 to be precise. Do

```
puts RUBY_VERSION
puts $:.inspect
```

on Ruby 1.8 (what's installed on your Mac) and Ruby 1.9.2 (what's installed on your windows machine) if you don't believe me.

[Why does Ruby 1.9.2 remove "." from LOAD_PATH, and what's the alternative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2900370/why-does-ruby-1-9-2-remove-from-load-path-and-whats-the-alternative/) discusses why "." was removed.