# Ruby: how to "require" a file from the current working dir?

Tags: ruby, require

How do I require a file from the current folder?

I have a file called `sql_parser.rb` that contains a class. I want to include this in another file also in the same folder, so I used:

```
require 'sql_parser'
```

That fails when I run from that folder:

```
LoadError: no such file to load -- sql_parser
```

I tried using IRB in the folder where this file exists and requiring it from there, but had the same issue.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2900370/why-does-ruby-1-9-2-remove-from-load-path-and-whats-the-alternative

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In ruby 1.9.x, you can use the method `require_relative`. See http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-require_relative.

Comment: Cheers! Looks like the proper way for me (1.9.2)

Answer (score 8):

Use

```
$:.unshift File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__))
```

to ensure that you're getting a path based on where the script is located, rather than where the program is being executed from. Otherwise, you're throwing away the security benefit gained by removing `"."` from the load path.

(Yes, the title of the question talks about requiring a file in the directory the script is being run from, but the body of the question mentions that the required file is in the same folder as the script in question)

Comment: Why is using "." less secure?  Also, why not Dir.pwd instead? (it's more concise and accomplishes the same thing no?)

Comment: @bkempner: Have you read the question linked to in the comments section of this question?

Comment: @AndrewGrimm, +1 I can always rely on you to write well-informed and proper answers. Thanks for avoiding `require_relative`. To those that care, **this is the correct way to do load files**

Answer (score 4):

also...

require "./myRubyFile" # notice we exclude the .rb from myRubyFile.rb

Answer (score 3):

On 1.9 the syntax changed to `require_relative`, as the other answers to this question said.

If you are writing in Ruby 1.8, I suggest writing your code in a forward looking manner, and using the [require_relative gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/require_relative), so you can use this keyword in your Ruby 1.8 and deal with one less transitional thing when you move to 1.9

Comment: This answer should be a comment to the solution, not an answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
$LOAD_PATH << Dir.pwd
require 'sql_parser'
```

As noted by @AndrewGrimm, due to security reasons, you should use this instead:

```
$LOAD_PATH << File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__))
require 'sql_parser'
```

Your directory has to be in the current load path.  The load path is stored in a global array called `$LOAD_PATH`.  If you append your current directory to it, then you can use require to load any files within the directory.

Using Dir.pwd instead of `pwd`.chomp as suggested by the Tin Man

Also I prefer this over require_relative unless you have a really small project otherwise things can get ugly.

Comment: Cheers. That works, but I thought ruby would always look in the pwd, am I wrong?

Comment: @Matt Roberts unfortunately not, but if you're working in a rails app all of that is handled for you.

Comment: @MattRoberts: It depends on the ruby version.

Comment: Ruby's `Dir.pwd` is probably more straightforward as it doesn't need to open a sub-shell or `chomp` the result. Also, with 1.9+, `require_relative './sql_parser'` or `require_relative 'sql_parser'` would be how I'd to go about it

Comment: How is `$LOAD_PATH << Dir.pwd` any less unsecure than `$LOAD_PATH << "."`? At least with the latter you know that you're doing something unsecure.

Comment: @knut true 1.8.7 require included current directory, i assumed he was using ruby 1.9.2.  Trolls - why the down votes?  If you down vote, at least explain your reasoning.  I'd certainly like to know if there is a better approach.

Comment: @bkempner: I downvoted. Would you rather I put "-1" in my comment?

Comment: @AndrewGrimm Oh i see the issue now that i read the link.  Thanks.

Comment: I'm using ruby 1.9.2, so it looks like require_relative should do the trick for me - but this is interesting stuff.