# Requiring a file in ROR

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a controller which wish to include a file in another folder, how do I do that? I am using Ruby 1.9.2 and Rails 3.2.6. Thanks

Controller file is in

```
/project/app/controllers/examples_controller.rb
```

and the required file is in

```
/project/example_folder/example.rb
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
require File.join(Rails.root, "example_folder", "example")
```

assuming /projects/ is your rails application root folder

Answer (score 0):

according to [here](http://extensions.rubyforge.org/rdoc/classes/Kernel.html#M000039)

more info here [Why does Ruby 1.9.2 remove "." from LOAD_PATH, and what's the alternative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2900370/why-does-ruby-1-9-2-remove-from-load-path-and-whats-the-alternative)

```
requie_relative '../../example_folder/example.rb'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can   auto load custom directories with classes and modules you want to be.

So you can Edit **config/application.rb**

```
# Custom directories with classes and modules you want to be autoloadable.
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/example_folder)
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be something like this:

```
require "#{Rails.root}/example_folder/example.rb"
```

just before the declaration of your controller.