# Calling a function in other file in Ruby

Tags: ruby, function, require

I have a hash like this in `file1.rb`

```
#file1.rb

h1 = {"k1"=>"v1", "k2"=>"75.1%"}

formatting (h1) #Function in file2.rb
```

From this file, I want to call a function in `file2.rb` and pass this hash `h1`

```
#file2.rb

def formatting(h1)
.
.
.
end
```

How can I do it in Ruby?

Comment: We need to see your attempts beyond those tiny code outlines. Show how you're trying to load the second file. Do you get errors? "Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See http://SSCCE.org for guidance. " This is answered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2900370/why-does-ruby-1-9-2-remove-from-load-path-and-whats-the-alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the method [***`Kernel#require_relative`***](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Kernel.html#method-i-require_relative).

I assumed here that both the files are under same directory `/home/kb/Ruby`.

**file1.rb**

```
require_relative 'file2.rb'
h1 = {"k1"=>"v1", "k2"=>"75.1%"}
formatting (h1)
```

**file2.rb**

```
def formatting(h1)
 #code
end
```