# Error while interpreting a class in ruby

Tags: ruby, file, require

I am trying to run this piece of Ruby code but getting an error , what seems to be the problem ?

```
require 'restaurant'

class Guide
  def initialize(path=nil)
    #locate the restaurant text file at path
    Restaurant.filepath=path
    if Restaurant.file_exists
      puts "Found restaurant file"
      #or create a new file
    elsif Restaurant.create_file
      puts "Created restaurant file"
      #exit if create fails
    else 
      puts "\n\nExiting\n\n"
      exit!
    end
  end
end
```

this is the error I get:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- restaurant (LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from guide.rb:1:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Please indent your code! This will not also help us but you will also benefit from proper formatting when reading your own code later.

Answer (score 1):

When you require a file from ruby, it looks for this file in all directories of the global variable `$LOAD_PATH` (also abbreviated with `$:`). This does typically *not* include the current directory (referred to as `./`), so you need to tell Ruby explicitly to look there:

```
require './restaurant'
```

Another option is to use `require_relative`:

```
require_relative 'restaurant'
```

If you like you can also append your current directory to `$LOAD_PATH`.

```
$: << File.expand_path(__FILE__)
require 'restaurant'
```

As a side note, before Ruby 1.9.2 the current directory was actually in `$LOAD_PATH`, also see [Why does Ruby 1.9.2 remove "." from LOAD_PATH, and what's the alternative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2900370/why-does-ruby-1-9-2-remove-from-load-path-and-whats-the-alternative)

Answer (score 0):

The error message is more than descriptive here. Ruby simply cannot find 'restaurant.rb' file, which you're trying to require.