# How can I start my thin server using ruby? require': cannot load such file -- app (LoadError)

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I want to start my app using thin server

In config.ru

```
require 'sinatra'

require 'app'
run Sinatra.application
```

they are on the same directory

```
kithokit@19:05:26 hello (master) $ ls config.ru app.rb 
app.rb  config.ru
```

but i still got this error

```
kithokit@19:05:14 meet-api (master) $ thin start
Using rack adapter
/home/kithokit/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- app (LoadError)
        from /home/kithokit/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line

```
require 'app'
```

to

```
require './app'
```

for more alternatives also see: [Why does Ruby 1.9.2 remove "." from LOAD_PATH, and what's the alternative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2900370/why-does-ruby-1-9-2-remove-from-load-path-and-whats-the-alternative)

Comment: A bit confused. I use ruby-1.9.3, which mean require 'app' should work. but u are right, we need to add "./" Do you know why? Any more reference?

Comment: Is it better to use $LOAD_PATH.unshift('.') rather than $LOAD_PATH << '.'  ?

Comment: Unshift will prepend the path. This means your own classes are loaded in favor of gems etc with the same name. Normally you will avoid name collisions so in practice i guess it does not matter.

Comment: If you read carefully, you will notice that `./` is necessary with *1.9.2 and above* which means it will only work the "old way" up until 1.9.1. You have 1.9.3, which does not have `./` in `$LOAD_PATH`.