# Loading a Ruby file in Windows 7. How do I do this? Loadpath issue?

Tags: ruby, load-path

I can't seem to load files. I am using Ruby 2.0.0 x64 and the built in command prompt with Ruby.

I have 2 problems.
1) If I use Powershell or the cmd.exe, I can't access Ruby if I type in irb. Any idea how to connect the two.

2) So instead I use the downloaded command prompt with Ruby. I have a file created called banking.rb. I am trying to load the file so I can test my code. Here is the location of my file:

C:\Users\Jwan\Desktop\Ruby Programs.

When I type in load 'banking.rb', I get this error:

```
LoadError:  cannot load such file -- banking.rb  
    from <irb>:6:in 'load'
    from <irb>:6
    from C:/Ruby200-x64/bin/irb:12:in '<main>'
```

So my guess is that the ruby loadpath is incorrect? The folder where this file is located is on my desktop. How do I change my loadpath (full disclosure:, please try to dumb down the instructions. I didn't even know what loadpath was prior to this post)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2900370/why-does-ruby-1-9-2-remove-from-load-path-and-whats-the-alternative/2900545#2900545 [basically, ruby doesn't load from the current working directory anymore]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [Ruby docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Kernel.html#method-i-load) for `Kernel.load`:

> Loads and executes the Ruby program in the file `filename`. If the
>   filename does not resolve to an absolute path, the file is searched
>   for in the library directories listed in `$:`.

So you can either type the absolute path

```
load 'C:\Users\Jwan\Desktop\Ruby Programs\banking.rb'
```

or modify `$:`

```
$: << 'C:\Users\Jwan\Desktop\Ruby Programs'
load 'banking.rb'
```

`$:` can also be referenced with `$LOAD_PATH`. It is the array of directories that Ruby searches for files to load. If you want to permanently add directories to your load path, you can set the `RUBYLIB` environment variable to a colon-separated list of them (look up how to do this on Windows, it's nestled deep in some menu).

Comment: It works! But what does $: << do? What does Kernel mean?

Comment: Also, is there a way for the library directories to always include C:\Users\Jwan\Desktop\Ruby Programs even if I restart teh command prompt? Also can I users backslashes instead of forward slashes in Windows 7?

Comment: `Kernel` is where all of Ruby's "global functions" (`load`, `puts`, `exit`, etc.) live. See my edited answer for your other question.